# codeigniter: why is that everytime i set a specific routing rule that page's css/js don't get loaded?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I'm building my website in codeigniter, and here an example of a routing rule that's giving me some trouble:

```
$route['updategamepage/(:num)'] = 'maincontroller/main/updategamepage/$1';
```

So is there anything wrong with the format/structure of the rule?  Here is an example url that uses that rule:

http://www.mydomain.com/ci_website/updategamepage/6

and when that page gets loaded, the css/js don't get loaded with the page...any idea on whats going wrong?

Comment: I assume `http://mydomain.com/ci_website/maincontroller/main/updategamepage/6` works fine?

Comment: How to you include your css/js ? Can you add that code in too.

Comment: @jeemusu yes the url is just the "mydomain.com" is the name i used for this post, I don't want to include the full url for security purposes, but if i were to include the full url(actual domain name) everyting is working, just this routing issue im having trouble with...

Comment: The reason I asked you to include your css/js call code is to check if your using <?php echo base_url();?> in front of your css/js URLs.  You will also have to set the base_url in the config, if you haven't already.

Comment: let me check my config files for the base setting.  And ill will go through and accept answers, thanks.

Comment: ok so when i use the <?php base_url(); ?> this what it spits out:  http://mydomain.com/ci_website/maincontroller/main/updategamepage,  when it shouldn't include the updategamepage segment...any reason why thats happening?

Comment: Spits that out where?  You mean to say that it **should** include the updategamepage segment right? For the javascript and css links, your echoing the variable right, `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` not just `<?php base_url(); ?>` . And, just to confirm, `$config['base_url']` is set to `'http://mydomain.com/ci_website/'`?

Comment: yes to all the above...and it shouldn't include the updategame segment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing rule should only apply to things that get routed through CodeIgniter's index.php file. That routing is dictated by the application's .htaccess file. It's possible that your htaccess is redirecting requests to your .css file to CodeIgniter when you don't want it to.

Ultimately you may way to check your web server logs, including potentially enabling mod_rewrite logging, to see what's actually going on.

Here is an example .htaccess that I use for my CodeIgniter apps:

(Notice you will have to change the RewriteBase directive near the top)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short `.htaccess` snippet I always use in my projects, it's much easier to understand.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|shared|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

what it does is that it redirects every url that doesn't contain `index.php`, `assets`, `shared`, `uploads` and `robots.txt` right after the URL to your public folder to your `index.php` file allowing you to set your `$config['index_page']` value to '', that will make your URL's much more pleasant for the eye and search engines. Without this you had URL's like `http://www.mysite.com/index.php/pages/about`, with it you will have `http://www.mysite.com/pages/about`.

Personally I keep my `JS` and `CSS` files in `assets` folder, but if you like to keep them in the root folder, simply add their folder names to the second line of the `.htaccess` file I provided separated with a `|` sign

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|shared|uploads|robots\.txt)
```

As I suggested in my answer to your other question a few minutes ago, you better erase the contents of your `$config['base_url']` value and let CodeIgniter do the job for you - he does it really well.